# Method can only be called again if 3 seconds is passed

Tags: c#, .net

I want to implement some way to prevent a method from being called several times instantly. for example imagine if I have a class like:

```
class Example
{
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

User can call `MyFunction` but only if 3 seconds is passed since the last time it's called. If it's called before 3 seconds, nothing should happen (Call should be ignored).

How would I do that?

Edit:

I don't want to use `Thread.Sleep`. I was thinking of maybe using Timer class from `System.Timer`. But don't know how I would use it for my need.

Comment: What do you want to happen if they do call it more frequently, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can declare private `DateTime` field of the class, store last invokation time there and check it when necessary.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I don't want to block the thread.

Comment: And you need to add the additional information of what you want to happen if the rule is violated. Do you want an exception to be thrown?

Comment: @JonSkeet Nothing should happen on that case.

Comment: So the call should be ignored, and return immediately? Please document that in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. It should be ignored.

Comment: In that case you could create class DateTime field which record the last time the Method is called. Upon the Method call, you check if the last time the Method is called differ by at least three seconds from the current time

Comment: It might be more useful to give us a summary of what you are actually trying to achieve as there seems some unexplained restrictions. For example, why specifically 3 seconds? What is your method doing? Perhaps if these sorts of things were answered a completely different / better way might be possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any need to use a timer here. You can use a [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
class Example
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan MinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); // Stopped initially

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        if (stopwatch.IsRunning && stopwatch.Elapsed < MinInterval)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // Do stuff here.
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this *isn't* thread-safe... multiple threads could execute the method at the same time, on the same instance. Each instance uses a separate stopwatch though, so there could be multiple instances being used by multiple threads - if you want to prohibit calls across *all* instances, you'd want to use a static field for the stopwatch, and definitely add locking in order to access it safely.

Also note that although you could use a `DateTime` to detect the last execution time, that can easily go wrong via the user changing the system clock.

The use of `try`/`finally` here is to avoid multiple calls in quick succession which fail due to exceptions being thrown. Again, that may not be what you want... you should consider whether you *do* want the stopwatch to be reset when a call fails.

Answer (score 4):

Do it with `Diagnostics.Stopwatch`:

```
class Program
{
    static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        Todo();
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Todo();
    }

    public static void Todo()
    {
        if(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 3)
        {
            // do stuff
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @sr28: That's only an example, in the `Main` method.

Comment: This answer never starts the stopwatch at the moment.

Comment: It does at stopwatch.Start();

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen that. But `Reset()` will stop it, and it won't be restarted...

Answer (score 3):

You can declare private `DateTime` field of the class, store last call time of your method there and check the difference with current time:

```
class Example
{
    private DateTime _MyFunctionLastCallTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    private object _Lock = new object();

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        lock(_Lock)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if ((now - _MyFunctionLastCallTime).TotalSeconds < 3)
                return;

            _MyFunctionLastCallTime = now;
            // the rest of code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have forgot to initialize `_Lock`. It should be also `readonly`

Comment: Using `DateTime.Now` here is a *really* bad idea, due to daylight saving time or other time zone changes. Using `UtcNow` would also be a bad idea in terms of the purpose of the code being subverted by the user changing their clock.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for pointing at `UtcNow`. Concerning user who can change system time.... well, surely it is possible but "danger" of it depends on OP's environment. Probably it is the code runnign at some server where such a time change less possible, who knows...

Comment: Well it needn't be actual user action, of course... It could just be time sync. The point is that DateTime isn't good for measuring elapsed time, whereas Stopwatch is.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to "block" anything nor do anything related to threads, just store the time when it was was last executed and exit (or throw an exception or do whatever you want) if it was called too shortly since

```
private DateTime LastCalled;
public void MyFunc()
{         
    if (LastCalled > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-3)
    {
         return; // or do whatever else you want, throw an exception etc
    };
    LastCalled = DateTime.Now;
    // Your actual method code here
}
```

Comment: Using DateTime.Now here is a really bad idea due to time zone issues. Also, the value of `LastCalled` can never be null as `DateTime` is a `struct`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Very good point on the DateTime.Now, will drop the null check (and default(datetime) should work fine as a default value) but yes DateTime.Now would be a bad idea in production for exactly what you mentioned